# How to set Dictionary as a property ? Give an example

Tags: c#, .net, properties, getter-setter

I'm trying to use a dictionary as a class member. I want to
use a property to get/set the key/value of the dictionary but I'm
confused as how to use a dictionary as a property. Since there are 2
parts, I don't know how to setup the get/sets.

Comment: Post what you have tried.

Comment: You will probably have to use the dictionary functions (Add/Remove) on the dictionary property like this: `MyObjInstance.dictionaryProperty.Add("key", value);`.

Comment: Dictionary as a property should expect a Dictionary object to be set and returned through get. Setting a value in the property 'set' doesn't seem right because it is a kind of collection. Better you can have the dictionary as a field and expose a couple of methods 'Add', 'Remove' and do the manipulations with the dictionary.

Comment: I have solved my self. Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
class Example {
  private Dictionary<int,string> _map;
  public Dictionary<int,string> Map { get { return _map; } }
  public Example() { _map = new Dictionary<int,string>(); }
}
```

Implementation would go along the lines of:

```
var e = new Example();
e.Map[42] = "The Answer";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
public static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
    var cl = new cl();
    populate(cl.dict);

    foreach(var d in cl.dict)
        Console.WriteLine(d.Key);
}

private static void populate(Dictionary<int, string> d)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10 ;  i++)
    {
        if (!d.ContainsKey(i))
        {
            d.Add(i, i.ToString());
        }
    }
    }
}

public class cl
{
    public Dictionary<int, string> dict;
    public cl()
     {
       dict = new Dictionary<int, string>();
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this ?

```
class MyDictionary<TKey, TValue>
{
    private readonly Dictionary<TKey, TValue> _dictionary;

    public void Add(TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        _dictionary.Add(key, value);
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        _dictionary.Clear();
    }

    public bool Remve(TKey key)
    {
        return _dictionary.Remove(key);
    }
```

.... and other methods...

```
    public MyDictionary(Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary)
    {
        _dictionary = dictionary;
    }
}
```